# why does user lookup field that is added in formula field is giving me its record id?

Tags: formula-field

why does user lookup field that is added in formula field is giving me its record id ?

Related_Opportunity__r.Account.ConversionOwner__c

Comment: What you want to be returned? Name?
Did you try some like this:
Related_Opportunity__r.Account.ConversionOwner__r.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, querying a lookup field always returns the Id of the lookup record. For instance, `Related_Opportunity__r.CustomLookUpField__c` will return the record Id of the look up record. If you wish to find other details connected to the lookup record, you need to access those fields in form of dot notation. For example, `Related_Opportunity__r.CustomLookUpField__r.Name` will give you the name. I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

That'd be because the lookup field stores the Id.

When you include a lookup field on a page layout, Salesforce is automagically turning that into a hyperlink to the related record and displaying the record name. That's done for our convenience.